# SAPI with Dephi: Async speech doesn't work

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, sapi, text-to-speech

The following works perfectly (Delphi 7):

```
procedure TMainForm.SayIt(s:string); // s is the string to be spoken
var
voice: OLEVariant;
begin
  memo1.setfocus;
  voice := CreateOLEObject ('SAPI.SpVoice');
  voice.Voice := voice.GetVoices.Item(combobox1.ItemIndex); // current voice selected
  voice.volume := tbVolume.position;
  voice.rate := tbRate.position;
  voice.Speak (s, SVSFDefault);
end;
```

The above works in "sync" mode (**SVSFDefault** flag), but if I change the flag to **SVSFlagsAsync** in an attempt to play the sound in async mode, no soud is produced. No error messages are given, but nothing is played on the speakers.

What might the problem be? I have the SpeechLib_TLB unit in Delphi's Imports folder.

**EDIT:** This is in Windows XP

Thanks,
Bruno.

Comment: Long time ago I played with SAPI, in order to make it async, I've created a thread with a queue which proved to work quite nice.

Answer (score 8):

When you uses the [SVSFlagsAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720892%28v=vs.85%29) flag, the voice stream is queued in an internal buffer and stay waiting to be executed by the speech service, So I think which you  issue is related to the lifetime of the voice object, because is a local variable , the instance is destroyed before to execute the sound.

As workaround you can wait for the sound, using the [`WaitUntilDone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723616%28v=vs.85%29) method

```
  voice.Speak (s, SVSFlagsAsync);
  repeat  Sleep(100); until  voice.WaitUntilDone(10);
```

or declare the `voice` variable in you form definition.

```
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
   voice: OLEVariant;
   procedure SayIt(const s:string);
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

uses
   ComObj;

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TMainForm.SayIt(const s:string); // s is the string to be spoken
const
  SVSFDefault = 0;
  SVSFlagsAsync = 1;
  SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak= 2;
begin
  memo1.setfocus;
  voice.Voice := voice.GetVoices.Item(combobox1.ItemIndex); // current voice selected
  voice.volume := tbVolume.position;
  voice.rate := tbRate.position;
  voice.Speak (s, SVSFlagsAsync {or SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak});
end;


procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SayIt('Hello');
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  voice := CreateOLEObject('SAPI.SpVoice');
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  voice  := Unassigned;
end;

end.
```

As additional note, since you are using late binding you don't need the SpeechLib_TLB unit.

Comment: WaitUntilDone turns it into synchronous. So prob not what's needed. Last paragraph could alternatively be stated: if you are using import lib, then you could switch to early binding. +1